# How do I get string inside string (yaml)

Tags: java, yaml

I was making a minecraft plugin, and i wanna get string inside a string(stick/diamond), how do I do that

This is a minecraft plugin YAML

```
item:
  stick:
    name: Stick
    lore: just a stick
    amount: 5
    percent: 100
  diamond:
    name: Shiny Diamond
    lore: Shiny Shiny
    amount: 1
    percent: 50
```

and here is my java code

```java
Random r = new Random();
int result = r.nextInt(getConfig().getStringList("item").size());

String titem = getConfig().getStringList("item").get(result);

Material itemm = Material.getMaterial(titem);
int amount = getConfig().getInt(titem + ".amount");

if (rand.nextInt(100) < getConfig().getInt(titem + ".percent")) {

    ItemStack item = new ItemStack(itemm, amount);
    SkullMeta pm = (SkullMeta) item.getItemMeta();
    item.setItemMeta(pm);

    monster.getWorld().dropItem(e.getEntity().getLocation(), item);
}
```

It did nothing but this error :

> at cc.gorjoe.spigot.mobDie.Main.onEntityDeath(Main.java:50) ~[?:?]

Line 50 corresponds to the line `String titem = getConfig().getStringList("item").get(result);`

Comment: What error does it output ?

Comment: it said```String titem = getConfig().getStringList("item").get(result);``` this line error

Comment: Is there no error message ? It says just the line of the error ?

Comment: yep, It just said ```at cc.gorjoe.spigot.mobDie.Main.onEntityDeath(Main.java:50) ~[?:?]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, problem solved it can just done by a simple for loop

```
ArrayList<String> ran = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String x : getConfig().getConfigurationSection("item").getKeys(false)) {
    System.out.println(x + " oo");
    ran.add(x);
}
```